# Implementing JAVA 9 Modularity to existing microservice modules in STS

Tags: java-11, spring-tool-suite, modularity

How to implement Modularity feature to the existing micro service modules in Spring Tool Suite IDE..I have seen implementing in Intellij by creating module-info.java file. Is it same with STS. Can I create module-info.java file and add dependencies for that module

Expecting to implement modularity using  STS

Answer (score 0):

The Java tooling inside of the Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse is coming from the underlying Eclipse IDE and its Java tooling - which supports Java 9 and dealing with module-info.java files for a long time already.

You can find details in this post, talking about the various changes to support Java 9, including the module support:

https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2018/june/java9andbeyond.php